# Closing of a connection in WS-Security protected web service

Tags: soapui, apache-axis, ws-security

I have web services published using the axis 2 library. The normal sequence is : webservice sequence is as follows :

i) authenticate Service which gives a connectionToken
ii) AbsoluteNumberServer call  ( connection Token obtained above is passed to this service)
iii) Close  ( this actually closes the conneciton handles)

I can enable WS-Security using Username / Token. In this case I can just make a call to the AbsoluteNumber service, without calling authenticate or close. Things work fine with a custom client application. But the connection handles are not released as 'Close' service is not getting called ( as I do not call it explicitly).

When I using SOAPUI, I find that after calling 'AbsoluteNumber' service, the close service is getting called automatically.

Am I missing something in my custom applicaiton. I am assuming SOAP UI does the right thing.

Any explanation here will help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this question. Its my bad. The closing of connection handles were artifact of the code at my end. Basically I am talking to a EIS system for ansering the webserivces calls.

So in such scenario, the webservices are WS-Secured, the internal connection handles made by the service should be closed like file connections, db connection or an EIS connection.